# Is there a way to combine 2 decorators in python with or condition?

Tags: python, slack-api, python-decorators

I am using RTMclient to get slack message data. Here the type of message is 'message' which only gives us the data of parent thread. But I want the message data of replies.
On research I found it is 'message_replied' type. I want to include either message or message_replied in decorator.

Pfb a sample code.

```
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def respond(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    web_client = payload['web_client']
    rtm_client = payload['rtm_client']
    user_id = data.get("user")

text = data.get("text")
```

Here I want to use `@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message_replied')` also but with 'or' condition

Comment: you can create two functions with different decorators and inside every function run the same other function which will get payload.

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorator feature itself., but more about the internal implementation of this specific decorator.  The decorator *always* applies to the function. It is just the internal logic of this `run_on` decorator checked the `event`.  If the decorator itself does not support that, easiest workaround is to def 2 functions each decorated with the event you need, and delegate the call to your `respond`

Comment: furras anwer isbthe right one, just create another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `slack.RTMClient.run_on()`, you should be able to "stack" the decorators like so:

```
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message_replied')
def respond(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    web_client = payload['web_client']
    rtm_client = payload['rtm_client']
    user_id = data.get("user")
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: That was to be expected, since the name implies that they just register the function. Good find.